# sql-mode hard mode incorrect integer

Tags: mysql, nginx

I have a problem with `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'rank' at row 1`

I understand it has to do with sql-mode but when I goto /etc/mysql the only files I find is; my.cnf, mysql.cnf and my.cnf.fallback but it doesnt seem to include any sql-mode to be edited

what can I do and where should I add sql-mode?

im using nginx on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: could you give some more details; specifically what OS, what version of MySQL and what's the contents of your my.cnf/my.ini

Comment: I actually found where to put it, but even if I put it, it doesnt update. Now my MYSQL is broken and I cannot access phpmyadmin because I get this error :/ This happened after I updated the code I got and reloaded mysql. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this error occurs when you are trying to import data. It suggests you are trying to import a non-integer value `''` into an integer field. You should look at your data and schema design first. If you really do want to change these errors into warnings you have to remove  `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from the default `sql-mode`. This means you have to define sql-mode in you my.cnf/my.ini to include the *other* default modes

```
sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Once you have added this to the `[mysqld]` section of your `cnf`/`ini` you need to restart the server. I would recommend taking a backup of your configuration files first. You should also [review the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html), linked here for version 5.7, to ensure this is really what you want to do.

Comment: As an addendum, this will convert your `''` into `0`, again you should ensure this is what you want in *all* cases.

Comment: theres no my.cnf/my.ini though, this is the issue, I dont know where to put this. But what happens if I do this sql-mode, can it like attract hackers or what should I be cautious about?

Comment: I found where to put it and I restarted my mysql and nginx but it still didnt work